# Ember: Exchanging the model within an action-handler

Tags: ember.js

How can I change the data of the model on a route as a reaction on a user interaction like pushing the button?

I want to have a productsearch-route where the model holds the items. This set on items can change when the user clicks sets criteria and clicks search. I have a component which sends an action every time the user fills a form and presses the button "search". The route handles the action in

```
//rounte.js
action: {
  searchClicked: {
    var newdata = this.get('store').query('item', {...});
    this.set('model', newdata); //<<<< this is not working!!
  }
}
```

If im doing so, exceptions will approaching. Also im afraid that this can't work even if if there are no exceptions because the template wont update itself I guess.

However: 
How can I set(/completely exchange) the model from actions in a route?

Answer (score 3):

I could think of few ways:

1) use query params and force route to refresh the model when criteria changes. More can be found here : https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/, specially [Opting into a full transition](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/routing/query-params/#toc_opting-into-a-full-transition). But this might not suite your need if you can have multiple criterion.

2) Set model to the controller not the route.

```
actions: {
  searchClicked() {
    let promise = this.get('store').query('item', {...});
    promise.then(newData => {
         this.controller.set('model', newdata);
    });     
  }
}
```

but with controllers going away in future iteration of ember, I don't know if this is best solution either.

Comment: both are **good** ways! I personally use query params and thats really fun, but just setting the `model` on controller is not a bad idea at all! Do it and have fun! That controllers probably will go a way is no reason to avoid them at the moment! Also you could transition into the new model ...